# Не понимаю что надо добавить

Tags: typescript, nextjs

Всем привет есть проект на ts и next.js для меня это новые технологии, но надо сделать, вопрос следующий есть такая строка:

```
const Layout = ({ children, authData: { isAuth, urlAuth, users } }: LayoutProps): JSX.Element => {
```

когда пытаюсь запустить проект получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `isAuth` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Я понимаю, что видимо надо где то прописать, что если приходит undefined то что возвращать, но может я не прав, подскажите где прочесть про это либо как исправить, спасибо, если нужна какая-то еще информация, пишите уточню, спасибо

Comment: Вы хоть интерфейс покажите.

Comment: Там показывать нечего, два компонента, первый index.tsx делает запрос на сервер getAuth, далее передает данные в следующий layout.tsx, и все, мне кажется человек разбирающийся понимает откуда возникает данная ошибка и как ее фиксить, а гуглить нет смысла, я уже гугил

Comment: Я про LayoutProps. Ошибка то понятно откуда вылезает, там же все написано.

Comment: Все свойства прописаны как не обязательные почему вылезает не понятно.

Comment: Тут вопрос скорее в том, почему у вас isAuth вообще может быть undefined/null. Если я правильно понимаю, это булево значение статуса авторизации. Так просто передавайте по умолчанию false, ибо я так понимаю, что тайпскрипт просто не понимает передаваемый тип, который может быть undefined, а может быть boolean.

Comment: Undefined он потому что нет ответа от бека, пробовал передавать и true и false, все время эта ошибка

Comment: Вы явно что то не так делаете, а я играю в вангу, просто тратим время друг друга. Скорее всего поможет такой вариант, но у вас логика апи хромает. const Layout = ({ children, authData: { isAuth?, urlAuth, users } }: LayoutProps): JSX.Element => {